# auto uncheck product attribute

Tags: ubercart

Each of my products has it own attribute with an expiration date. How can I auto unchecked the option when it expires?

I know there is a module call [scheduler](https://www.drupal.org/project/scheduler) which can help to auto publish and unpublished the node. How about the attribute?

Answer (score 0):

Scheduler doesn't have any sort of integration with Ubercart. Unless there's existing module out there (I've never heard of it), you'll need a custom module that can hook into the attribute option form & display/store your expiration for each option (via `hook_form_alter`) & disable it when your option expires (via `hook_cron`).

Comment: @Shaen Thanks for your reply. How about only insert data expire date to attribute and I only will auto uncheck once expire. Not longer related to uber cart.